Blazor upgrading from .NET 6 to .NET 8 - NavigateTo not working
I am moving a functioning .NET 6 application to .NET 8.
This was a wholly WebAssembly project. I have retained that but use the server side rendering of the home page to improve the user experience.
I want to get a user to click an object on a page, log in and then return to that page, where using local storage to remember the object, it sorts it out and displays it etc.
So I need to redirect to the login page with a return url of "/" so not too hard, but it is not working and gets to 'Not Found'.
The code to do this is set up or called in the 'OnAfterRender' method so pretty sure it is local to the browser.
My Routes.Razor looks like this:
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

My App.razor has
<HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" /> 

with the code as follows:
public partial class App
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
                    ? null
                    : RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly;
}

This ensures that the Account code stays server side from the MS template code.
I am sure I am missing something stupid re the routing. I tried this too:
string reg = _navigationManager.GetUriWithQueryParameters("Account/Login", new Dictionary<string, object?> { ["ReturnUrl"] = "/" });
_navigationManager.NavigateTo(reg);

... and if I break on the NavigateTo line, the value for reg is null.
To try to simplify and encapsulate it further I took my login button and changed it (original code commented out):
    <div class="ctr">
        <div class="clnk">
            @* <Button Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary" Type="ButtonType.Link" To="Account/Login">Login/Sign Up</Button> *@
            <Button Size="Size.Small" Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="Login">Login/Sign Up</Button>
        </div>
    </div>

    public void Login()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("Account/Login");
    }

With the button it works fine as a link, not found when trying to route with NavigateTo...
What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.
EDIT
The route for the login page is as per the MS template code with an @page directive at the top:
@page "/Account/Login"

FURTHER EDIT
My App.razor is as follows:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
    GOOGLE STUFF
    <!-- END of Google tag (gtag.js) -->

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--Google Fonts-->
    GOOGLE FONTS STUFF
    <title>WMAP</title>
    <base href="/" />

    <!--OTHER SCRIPTS inside of head section -->
    LINKS TO OTHER SCRIPTS
    <!-- END OF OTHER SCRIPTS head section -->

    LINKS TO STYLESHEETS

    <link rel="icon" sizes="512x512" href="icon-512.png" />
    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="icon-192.png" />


        <!-- Meta Pixel Code -->
    META (FACEBOOK/INSTA) Code
    <!-- End Meta Pixel Code -->


    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>

    PAYMENT PROVIDER SCRIPTS
    
    <!-- WMAP JS-->
    <script src="/js/WMAP.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <!-- /WMAP JS-->
</body>

</html>



        public partial class App
        {

            [CascadingParameter]
            private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

            private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
                ? null
                : RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly;





        }


Could you please tell me how you define the route for the Account/Login? The account/login is the identity razor page or else?

Yes @BrandoZhang it is straight from the template code. I'll add it in a questions edit above.

Could you provide your App.razor?

Hi @MarvinKlein I have added the App.Razor and the .cs file (I keep them seperate.

I also found that using the 'force' option on the NavigateTo causes the Local Storage to get cleared... so am presently trying to work around this by feeding vars into my query strings.

I am not 100% sure if this is a true answer or work around as yet.
I'll take it under advisement. However, I found that if I make the call:
_navigationManager.NavigateTo("Account/Login",true);

The 'true' bool is the 'force load' option which bypasses client side routing.
I am not sure therefore if, depite being called via the onaafterrender, the page is in fact fully home on the client.
I am happy to take further feedback on this issue as the start up of the home page which is initially statically rendered on the server then re-rendered on the client after the WASM has downloaded still holds a few mysteries.
